# rxdart BehaviorSubject does not emit last value on iOS

Tags: dart, flutter, rxdart

I am building a Flutter app and have run into the following issue. Following the BLoC pattern, my code is structured like this:

BLoC:

```dart
class Bloc {
  final _subject = BehaviourSubject<Data>;

  Observable<Data> get stream => _subject.stream;

  void load() async {
    _subject.sink.add(Data.loading());
    final data = await /* ... */;
    _subject.sink.add(Data.success(data));
  }
}
```

State:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return StreamBuilder<Data>(
    stream: widget.bloc.stream,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      print(snapshot);
      if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data.isLoading) {
        return /* loadingindicator */;
      }

      return /* data view */;
    },
  );
}

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  widget.bloc.load();
}
```

On Android, everything works as expected. The build method gets called for
`Data.loading()` and for `Data.success()`.

On iOS, however, I do not receive any data at all (`snapshot.hasdata == false`). I added a button, which on click, listens to the stream and prints
the received value. On Android, I receive the last event, as it is expected with a BehaviorSubject. On iOS, the listen method did not get called.

Button:

```dart
MaterialButton(
  child: Text('Click me'),
  onPressed: () {
    widget.bloc.stream.listen(print); // prints Data.success on Android, nothing on iOS
  },
),
```

Comment: I seriously doubt that rxdart has a different behavior depending on platform. and I also challenge your assumption that the problem is, that you do not receive the last event. Since your StreamBuilder also never receives the event, even though it is listening.. are you sure there is no way that that there might be a `null` ending up in your stream? i would suggest in your `initState` to add a `widget.bloc.stream.listen((val) { print("debug: $val"); });` (BEFORE calling `load`) to see if anything is pushed into it at all..

Comment: Hi @herbert, thanks for your reply! I tried subscribing to the stream before calling load, and I did receive both Data.loading and Data.success. What I find really strange though, is that the `stream.listen(print)` I call when I click on the button does not print anything at all on iOS, but it does on Android. I'll try to isolate that behavior to check if it may be the problem. As you said, it would be strange if a dart-only library would behave differently on those two systems.

Comment: @herbert thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I've found the problem, and of course, it did not have a thing to do with rxdart. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found the problem. As @herbert pointed out to me, it was very unlikely that rxdart was the problem here.

I have looked into my code and found that my Page was being rebuilt, and because my code was looking like this, the bloc was re-instantiated. This somehow only happened on iOS and not on Android.

```dart
'page': (context) => MyPage(bloc: Bloc()),
```